# Evaluate the following integral:

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate:
$$\int_{}^{} \frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x}\, dx$$

where $a$ is a real parameter and $0<x<a$.

Comment: There is a clear lack of information. What is the domain?

Comment: Wellcome to MSE. If you make your question clear and show your trial, then you would obtain good feedback. Nice to meet you !

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $x = a\sin \theta$, then $a^2 - x^2 = a^2 - a^2\sin^2 \theta = a^2\cos^2 \theta$,

and $dx = a\cos \theta d\theta$

Comment: when I take the square root do I have to write:$$\sqrt{1-\cos^2 t}=\left | \sin t \right |$$

Answer (score 1):

set $x=a\cos(t)$ then you witll have
$a^2-a^2\cos(t)^2=a^2(1-\cos(t)^2)=a^2\sin(t)^2$ and
$dx=-a\sin(t)dt$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}x=\frac{x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x^2}$$

Setting $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=u\implies a^2-x^2=u^2\implies x\ dx=-u\ du$

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}xdx=-\int\frac{u^2}{a^2-u^2}du=\int du-a^2\int\frac{du}{a^2-u^2}$$

In case you don't want to memorize the last integral,

write $$\frac1{a^2-u^2}=\frac1{2a}\cdot\frac{a-u+a+u}{(a+u)(a-u)}=\cdots$$